# select all rows with sport=padel

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select all the content of the row when sport= padel.

My code is this:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sport FROM posts WHERE sport='padel'                
 ");
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ ?>

<div  class= 'box1'>
<p align='middle'><?php echo $row['username']; ?></p>
<h3 align='middle'>Playing</h3>
<h3 align='middle' style= 'color:blue'><?php echo $row['sport']; ?> </h3>
<div><p align='middle' >Disponibilidade:</p>
<h3 align='middle' style='color:blue'><?php echo $row['text']; ?></h3></div>
<p></p>
<h3 align='middle' style='color:blue'><?php echo $row['city']; ?></h3>
<button text-align='middle' id='submit1' type='submit1'> 
contact </button>
</div>
```

This, in fact, select all the row with sport=padel, but all the other content in the different columns is missed (gives me undefined variable)

I think I could do this:

```
 $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT sport FROM posts WHERE sport='padel'                
 WHERE text='' WHERE city=''");
```

but didn't work. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM` please, start learning SQL

Comment: Please RTM http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html - WHERE uses `AND|OR` and not multiple `WHERE`s. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimizations.html - *"I think i could do this:"* - No.

Comment: @chris85 [*You're a little late lol*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40577872/select-all-rows-with-sport-padel#comment68391228_40577872)

Comment: Aha, beat me again @Fred-ii-

Comment: @chris85 ;-) hehe oh well, GMTA ;-)

Comment: It was this SELECT * FROM that was missing. Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, you need to specify what columns you want to pull back, at the moment you are pulling back the sport column only.

`SELECT * FROM posts WHERE sport="padel"`

This will ensure you pull back all columns.  Alternatively you can specify multiple comma separated columns

`SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM posts WHERE sport="padel"`